# jQuery carousel new style next and prev on first and last slide

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, carousel

I'm very new with jQuery and I use this jQuery carousel. I don't want to use any plugin. But I want to ask how can I make  prev button with another style/color, when I am on first slide and how can I  make  next button with another style/color,, when I am on last slide.

here is demo

http://jsfiddle.net/rGLsG/24/

here is jQuery code

```
      $(function(){
     var carousel = $('.carousel ul');
       var carouselChild = carousel.find('li');
      var clickCount = 0;
     var canClick = true;

     itemWidth = carousel.find('li:first').width()+1; //Including margin


     carousel.width(itemWidth*carouselChild.length);


        refreshChildPosition();


        $('.btnNext').click(function(e){        
if($(".carousel").find("li:eq(6)").text()!=14) {
    if(canClick) {
        canClick = false;
        clickCount++;
        //Animate the slider to left as item width 
        carousel.stop(false, true).animate({
            left : '-='+itemWidth
        },300, function(){
            //Find the first item and append it as the last item.
            lastItem = carousel.find('li:first');
            lastItem.remove().appendTo(carousel);
            lastItem.css('left', ((carouselChild.length-1)*(itemWidth))+(clickCount*itemWidth));
            canClick = true;
        });
    }
}
```

});

```
         $('.btnPrevious').click(function(){
  if($(".carousel").find("li:eq(0)").text()!=1) {
    if(canClick){
        canClick = false;
        clickCount--;
        //Find the first item and append it as the last item.
        lastItem = carousel.find('li:last');
        lastItem.remove().prependTo(carousel);

        lastItem.css('left', itemWidth*clickCount);             
        //Animate the slider to right as item width 
        carousel.finish(true).animate({
            left: '+='+itemWidth
        },300, function(){
            canClick = true;
        });
    }
}
 });

       function refreshChildPosition(){
carouselChild.each(function(){
    $(this).css('left', itemWidth*carouselChild.index($(this)));
});
```

}

Comment: add an if statement into the previous click function? if(canclick==false){$(".btnPrevious").css("color","red")}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this
for previous button

```
var check = $(".carousel ul").position().left;
        if (check == 0)
        {
             $(".btnPrevious").css('color','red');  
        }
```

similar condition for next

```
 var cwidth = $(".carousel").width();
    var check = $(".carousel ul").position().left;
    if (check == -cwidth )
                {
                     $(".btnnext").css('color','red');  
                }
```

Comment: no, it doesn't work. Prev button ist all the time red, not only when it is only on first slide.

Comment: my friend you need to write your remaining code in the else part of the above if condition and remove the CSS of the button. Hope I have given you idea and logic rest you can try it your self..